# Element appending with and without scroll varies

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 button, one in top another in the bottom. when I click the top button it works fine. when i scroll down to bottom button and click the button again ( same function ) it appends the element with some where. I am calculating the top position from absolute way. getting the relation ship with body.

so how to handle this kind of scenario?

[Live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2B35qnvETBiXMCTh?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Js code :

```
const h1All = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

function addElement() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = "I am here";
  div.style.border = "1px solid green";
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  let h1 = h1All[0];
  h1.style.border = "1px solid red";
  let parentPos =  h1.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(parentPos)
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.style.top = parentPos.y + parentPos.height + "px";
}
```

HTML:

```
 <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="mydiv">some div info goes here
      <button onclick="addElement()">Click Me </button> //works fine.
    </div>
    <button onclick="addElement()">Click Me </button> //it's not. after scroll down!!
```

the second button appends the element some where. what is the correct way to calculation do we have to do here?

Thanks in advance.

```js
const h1All = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

function addElement() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = "I am here";
  div.style.border = "1px solid green";
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  let h1 = h1All[0];
  h1.style.border = "1px solid red";
  let parentPos =  h1.getBoundingClientRect();

  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.style.top = parentPos.y + parentPos.height + "px";
}
```

```css
.mydiv{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 600px; 
}
```

```html
 <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="mydiv">some div info goes here
      <button onclick="addElement()">Click Me </button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addElement()">Click Me </button>
```

Comment: What exactly is your task? I can't understand reading your appeal. :(

Comment: I require to position the element with scroll. when i do call the function by clicking the bottom button, element disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `absolute` positioning, you need to take scrolling into account. You can do that with `window.scrollY`. Notice the change at the last line of `addElement`:

```js
const h1All = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

function addElement() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = "I am here";
  div.style.border = "1px solid green";
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  let h1 = h1All[0];
  h1.style.border = "1px solid red";
  let parentPos =  h1.getBoundingClientRect();

  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.style.top = parentPos.y + parentPos.height + window.scrollY + "px";
}
```

```css
.mydiv{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 600px; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="mydiv">some div info goes here
      <button onclick="addElement()">Click Me </button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addElement()">Click Me </button>
```